# Building queries in Access 2007?

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

I'm trying to build a query where I'm able to get names of clients. So I have two tables, the 1st table has a column `AppointmentNO`, and this field is a number (there are other columns but they're irrelevant). In the 2nd table I have an `ID` as primary key, `FirstName`, `LastName`. `ID` is what matches the `AppointmentNO` in the first table.

Basically what I'm trying to do is link the two tables so that when I have an `AppointmentNO` in one column, I can see the `LASTNAME` associated with it in the 2nd column (need to include this in my report). I'm trying to link the `AppointmentNO` to `ID` and on JOIN PROPERTIES -> include all records from left table (1st table) and only those from right table (2nd table) where the joined fields are equal.

If I try to run the query it gives me a MISMATCH error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read if you showed your table structure rather than describing it in prose. It sounds like what you want to do is something like: SELECT LastName from [1stTable] WHERE [1stTable].AppointmentNo = [2ndTable].ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type mismatch error could be happening:

1. because the two fields that you're trying to join aren't set as the same data type (e.g. one is Number and the other is Text) - check this in the Properties tabs for the relevant fields in each table;
2. it could be that Access has a join between the tables involving other fields (it will sometimes do this with AutoIDs) - you can check the relationships (and establish them) in the Tools -> Relationships window (where this is located might depend on your version). You can also use this tool to explicitly build the relationship, by connecting your 'ID' to 'AppointNO' - though you should still ensure that the fields are of the same data type.

ADDITION:
Based on what you're describing, I think this is the situation (correct me if I'm wrong, though):

Three tables - Client, AppointmentNO, Children

In each table, there is a 'MemberID' - this is primary key in Client Table, and is Foreign Key in the other tables.

The Children and AppointmentNO tables are linked to Client table by one-to-many relationships (a client can have >1 children and >1 appointment).

I'd set this up so that the Member ID is the same datatype in each table, and join all tables on that field. Then, when set up a query that gives you MemberID, ClientName, ClientDOB (and anything else you want from the client table), ChildName, and AppointmentID. Once the query is working and giving you the desired output, you can build a report and group the output by Client and Client Description, so you'll get "Client A" followed by list of appointments and children, then "Client B" etc.

Hope that's clear-ish.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should be even building a query. The report is made up of 2 subreports. The main one is a client name with all the relevant information (DOB, Address). Then I add children to the report (using a subreport). I link them with master fields in properties window (with MemberID). The 2nd subreport (appointments) I also link with MemberID as it's in all three tables. There is no child names (just an auto ID not memberID). Children's names are in the Child table, and ID's that I'm trying to reference are in Appointment table.

Comment: So basically what I tried to do is link the child ID that appears in the 2nd(the one with no names, just ID's) subreport to children's table with CONTROL SOURCE, or what have you.

Comment: I'm trying to link the APOINTMENT subreport to CHILDREN's subreport, but as you pointed out, one is ID (numeric) and the names are varchar(25) so that's what's probably giving me the issue.  But still, how do I go about fixing it? Sorry for leaving so many comments, I'm kind of new with access so that's why I'm having this issue. The tables were not created in access but are actually imported from SQL-SERVER